# Ansible win_chocolatey install_args

Tags: windows, ansible, chocolatey, ansible-module

I try to install oracle sql developer on windows host with ansible with this task:

```
- name: Install oracle-sql-developer
  win_chocolatey:
    name: oracle-sql-developer
    version: '20.4.1.20210328'
    state: present
    install_args: "--params \"'/Username:{{ oracle_username }} /Password:{{ oracle_password }}'\""
```

The installation need /Username and /Password arguments but it's not working. I try many way to pass this arguments, but it doesn't work either. I always get this error message:

```
"ERROR:   An Oracle account is required to download SQL Developer",
        "",
        "  * Provide your Oracle credentials as package params to the installer and",
        "    retry the installation:",
        "",
        "    choco install oracle-sql-developer --params \"'/Username:{userName} /Password:{password}'\""
```

How can I get these arguments right?

Comment: try this `install_args: "--params \"/Username:{{ oracle_username }} /Password:{{ oracle_password }}\""`

Comment: @KrishnaReddy it's not working

Comment: Are these params source_username and source_password ? if yes then these arguments can be password directly not thru install_args. check [doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/chocolatey/chocolatey/win_chocolatey_module.html)

Comment: @KrishnaReddy RESOLVED with using package_params instead install_args
`package_params: "'/Username:{{ oracle_username }} /Password:{{ oracle_password }}'"`

Comment: You can close this question as resolved :)